# Can't use the data from API when app just starts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, es6-promise

My data is undefined when the app is started but after the refresh, the data comes perfectly.

For startup
It gives me [**Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Object.entries requires that input parameter not be null or undefined]**

But after the refresh, the data comes perfectly and everything working.

This is part of my data

```
Object {
  "attributes": Object {
    "htmlName": null,
    "id": 0,
    "items": Array [
      Object {
        "htmlName": "r_1",
        "name": "m2 (Brüt)",
        "numeric": true,
        "options": Object {},
        "order": 0,
        "required": true,
      },
      Object {
        "htmlName": "r_2",
        "name": "m2 (Net)",
        "numeric": true,
        "options": Object {},
        "order": 0,
        "required": true,
      },
      Object {
        "htmlName": "r_164",
        "name": "Arsa Alanı (m2)",
        "numeric": true,
        "options": Object {},
        "order": 0,
        "required": true,
      },
      Object {
        "htmlName": "a_137",
        "name": "Oda Sayısı",
        "numeric": false,
        "options": Object {
          "12": "1+0",
          "13": "1+1",
          "14": "1.5+1",
          "15": "2+0",
          "16": "2+1",
          "17": "2.5+1",
          "18": "2+2",
          "19": "3+1",
          "20": "3.5+1",
          "21": "3+2",
          "22": "4+1",
          "226": "0+1",
          "23": "4.5+1",
          "24": "4+2",
          "25": "4+3",
          "26": "4+4",
          "27": "5+1",
          "28": "5+2",
          "29": "5+3",
          "30": "5+4",
          "31": "6+1",
          "32": "6+2",
          "33": "6+3",
          "34": "7+1",
          "35": "7+2",
          "36": "7+3",
          "37": "8+1",
          "38": "8+2",
          "39": "8+3",
          "40": "8+4",
          "41": "9+1",
          "42": "9+2",
          "43": "9+3",
          "44": "9+4",
          "45": "9+5",
          "46": "9+6",
          "47": "10+1",
          "48": "10+2",
          "49": "10 Üzeri",
        },
        "order": 0,
        "required": true,
      },
```

**api.js**

```
  export const getData = function () {
  return axios
    .get(
      "blabla",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `blabla`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((json) => {
      if (json && json.status === 200) {
        //console.log(json);
        return json.data;
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

**App.js**

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [roomValue, setRoomValue] = useState(null);

  const [roomCount, setRoomCount] = useState([]);
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataFunc();
    //setDropdown(data.attributes.items[3].options);
  }, []);

  const getDataFunc = async () => {
    const res = await getData();
    //console.log(res);
    setData(res);
    console.log(data);
  };

  function setDropdown(query) {
    const response = query;
    try {
      const entries = Object.entries(response);
      const tempArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        var key;
        var value;
        (key = entries[i][0]), (value = entries[i][1]);
        tempArray.push({ key: value, value: key });
      }
      setRoomCount(tempArray);
      //console.log(roomCount);
    } catch (error) {
      //console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a seperate useEffect to check wheather the data has been set and then only set the dropdown values

```
   useEffect(() => {
    getDataFunc();
   }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(data && data.attributes?.items[3]){
       setDropdown(data.attributes.items[3].options);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const getDataFunc = async () => {
    const res = await getData();
    //console.log(res);
    setData(res);
    console.log(data);
  };
```

Comment: It still gives the same problem, data has been set after refresh. I can log the res perfectly but if I need to log data it needs a refresh

Comment: so you can't see the console log in the initial load?

Comment: Wait... Sorry for late response but I guess it's working now. First, it gives me null but using seperate useEffect function is make it work. I can use my data inside the dropdown without refresh. But I can't see the log of my data in the console without refresh. Intresting...

Comment: you need to console the `res` not `data` because `setData` is an asynchronous event. it won't update the state variable immediately. That's why we need a separate useEffect to catch the `data` changes

Comment: Hmm so if I understand right, it is not a problem, right? Thank you one more time

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the error is caused by the attributes property being empty when you try to access it. But when you assign them one by one then it loads because the data is loaded per nested property before assigning it to the variable. Means it hasn't fully loaded yet

```
const response = data.attributes.items[3].options;
```

It outputs an error because attributes is undefined. So it's not an object, therefore, attributes.items is considered invalid

```js
// sample

const data = {
  /* attributes: {
    items: {
      1: {
        options: 'option1'
      },
      2: {
        options: 'option2'
      },
      3: {
       options: 'option3'
      }
    }
  } */
}


const specificData = data.attributes.items[3].options

console.log(specificData) //
```

So one solution would be using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#:%7E:text=Description-,Optional%20chaining%20(%3F.),instead%20of%20throwing%20an%20error.) to avoid the error, it's just basically a `question mark (?)` after the object you are trying to access.

The response would be then '`undefined`'. That way even if the `attributes` is empty or not, data will be assigned to the response constant then you can just add some more checking outside of that.

```js
    // sample

    const data = {
      /* attributes: {
        items: {
          1: {
            options: 'option1'
          },
          2: {
            options: 'option2'
          },
          3: {
           options: 'option3'
          }
        }
      } */
    }


    const specificData = data.attributes?.items[3].options

    console.log(specificData) // outputs undefined instead of an error
```

Let me know if this works btw. maybe you could provide the actual api or maybe a sample api endpoint so we could test it directly. Or maybe the full code?

I've encoutered this before though I'm not 100% sure this is all I've done. But for the error I'm sure the *optional chaining operator* will prevent it

Comment: Thanks for your optional chaining operator approach. It helps me much. After a couple of debugging it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling getData inside an async function and wait for the process to complete like this in your **App.js**

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [roomCount, setRoomCount] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    getDataFunc()
}, []);

const getDataFunc = async() => {
    await getData(setData);
    const response = data;
    console.log(response);
    const entries = Object.entries(response);
    const tempArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      var key;
      var value;
      (key = entries[i][0]), (value = entries[i][1]);
      tempArray.push({ key: value, value: key });
    }

    setRoomCount(tempArray);
    console.log(roomCount);
}
```

note: The best practice is not to directly pass the setData function to getData api call instead return the response from api and assign the response in main code like below

```
const response = await getData();
setData(response)
```

Comment: Hey, I changed the code in light of your comment, I was working on the code for a while and my errors have a bit changed now. I updated the whole description. Can you check again please. I understand that my data is not showing at the startup and because of that it gives me promise error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your `data.attributes` has `undefined` value.
Please double-check everything, it is technically impossible to get data directly if `data.attributes` is `undefined`

Comment: Yes, it gives me undefined at first but when I refresh it becomes normal and I can get the data, I shared the part of data as JSON. Can you check it please?

Comment: how did you parse that data? Share please that part of the code.

Comment: how are you doing requests to the server?

Comment: I shared the API connection and my main App.js file, can you check it one more time